# Setting opacity for only outer div, NOT inner texts

Tags: html, css, text, opacity

I have a div and inside of it, I have lots of texts.
I set the div's opacity to 0.7, but by  this way, my texts also get transparent. 
I want my texts to seem solid, NOT transparent.

I have made a research about it, everyone talking about div > div's. my problem ain't that.

Comment: Please post some HTML/CSS so we can see what you are doing.  At the moment, your question is too broad.

Comment: thanks for your intend to help. problem has been solved by first answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want background color with opacity den you can use `rgba()`

```
background:rgba(100,100,100,0.8);
```

the first thee numbers representing the color in RGB and the fourth representing opacity.

Comment: thanks, now I see the problem wasn't related with inner element's type. I thought texts would have some different property about opacity.Thanks.. that works well..